# Validating a text box value using JavaScript

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have a textbox.T he user will be entering entering a number in this box. The user should enter two digits followed by a period "." and another digit. It would look something like 22.3 or 00.5 or 01.2.

If the textbox is not empty, I want to enforce a function which validates the value entered by the user (and gives them an alert if the value entered is not according to the format mentioned above). This function needs to be triggered when the textbox loses its focus. I am not sure how to go ahead in writing this function as I am still new to this.
Any help would be appreciated.

p.s. This function should be triggered each time there is a change in the value. Like suppose, the user enters a value 22, then when the textbox loses its focus, the JavaScript function should be triggered giving them an alert asking the user to change it to the accepted format which is 22.0.The function should be triggered again when the textbox loses its focus (after the change has been done). This time there would not be an alert since the user entered it in the right format.

Comment: If you're not adversed to using jQuery, it makes it extremely simple:
http://docs.jquery.com/Plugins/Validation

Then you can just wire up client-side event handlers (e.g "$(#mytextbox).change(function {) and call the .validate function

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Excuse the Prototype specific code, but maybe you'll get the gist of it. You'll want to listen on the "onblur" event of the textarea, and then validate the entered value with a regular expression.

```
Event.observe('textboxId', blur, function() {
  var val = $F('textboxId');
  if (/^\d{2}\.\d$/.test(val)) {
    alert('Invalid value');
  }
});
```

If you're not familiar with any javascript frameworks, and just want to get this working, try this:

```
<textarea onblur="validate(this.value);"></textarea>

<script type="text/javascript">
function validate(val) {
  if (/^\d{2}\.\d$/.test(val)) {
    alert('Invalid value');
  }
}
</script>
```

Purists, please don't punish me for adding this.

Comment: Thank you lauri, i am going to try this.