# validating and focusing an element

Tags: javascript, asp.net

I want to validate an ASP.TextBox for entering only Integer Value with javascript function.  In case of non-Integer value entered by a user, it should displays a warning message and keeps the focus on current element.  I used the following procedure:

On Web Page’s Asp.TextBox element:

```
onchange="return isInteger(this);" onblur="return isInteger(this);"
```

And valdating function in functions.js file

```
function isInteger(mobj) {
var mval = mobj.value;
if (isNaN(parseInt(mval))) {
    alert("Plese Enter a Valid Integer...!");
    mobj.focus();
    return false;
}
 return true; 
}
```

Is it correct, or is there any correct way to do the validation. Kindly suggest.

Comment: There is no jQuery in this question.

Comment: Please do not restrict blur on invalid input. Please do not shove dialog box in user's face. If you are bent on coding client-side validation, just show an inline error message.

Answer (score 0):

Yes idea is correct. Thats how you have to validate your textbox.

[Validating a text box value using javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986768/validating-a-text-box-value-using-javascript)

http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/netfxjscript/thread/07a91c1d-34db-44d8-9bd6-a424394a7028/

Or there is another way using onKeyUp() on text box, check the value of textbox, and return false if input is not an integer.

Answer (score 0):

You can use ASP.NET **RegularExpressionValidator** Control for validating your text box input value.

Eg.

```
<asp:TextBox id="textbox1" runat="server" />
<asp:RegularExpressionValidator
ControlToValidate="textbox1"
ValidationExpression="\d{1,10}"
ErrorMessage="Plese Enter a Valid Integer...!"
runat="server" />
```

Answer (score 0):

The idea is correct but onchange is enough. onblur is not necessary because you don't want to validate each time the control lost focus(i.e. tab through or just click) without having any change.

Answer (score 0):

`onblur` is enough for validation here..

Using `onchange` and `onblur` together will create two alerts sometimes i.e when focus is lost and `onchange` fires together...

Try [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fCnBY/)...

If you use onchange alone, you will get alert only first time you lose the focus when you keep text unchanged ..like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fCnBY/1/)... or else your have to clear textbox value if it is invalid...

`onkeyup` can be a best alternative but still you may need to clear textbox value like [here](http://jsfiddle.net/fCnBY/2/)...